# Open a Angular Directive element in a new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So suppose my element is

```
<my-element myName="simpleElement" isBold="yes" value="Apple">
```

and my directive does nothing but prints

"Apple" (Printed in bold)

I then have a button that needs to open the same element in a new window, so my output in the new window show also be "Apple" (printed in bold).

Any idea how do we do this ?

Comment: can use postMessage API to pass data between windows

Comment: Would you need to pass any data to the new window? Or just open this directive in the new window?

Comment: @shivas i need to pass data to the new window. In this above example you can assume the data to be passed to be Apple